# setting constraints on contentView inside scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

For my project I need to make a custom menu with the height of 64 pt from the top. So default navigation bar visibility is set to false. Under this menu I have a ScrollView which contains a ContentView where I will place all my UI items. ContentView's origin,which is inside the ScrollView, is (0,0). Problem is that when I run the project ContentView is being displayed after leaving 20 pt space from top of SrcollView.

Here is Sample Project link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzhZns5G0PXhN2lNSjF6XzNmTTg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue seen in Scroll Views and Table Views. Add this line of code to resolve it:

`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;`

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue. But can u explain, if we don't set it to false why it always appear after 20 pt. This is the size of status bar

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your code:

```
var gg:CGSize = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
self.scrollView.contentSize = gg
```

And add this line instead of that code:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: this solved the issue, but is it right to set the top -20 when we know it starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

i have made changes for you,use this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97G6aGaHcoYNUVtMmN1b1dUR2M/view?usp=sharing